# Where are the "exclude folders/files from build" and "exclude files larger than X in search" settings in Intelllij 14

Tags: intellij-idea

Those settings used to be under some combination of

> File|Settings

and

> Intellij|Preferences

in earlier versions of IJ. But after having searched all of the menu items I can locate either one in IJ14.

I have searched all the menu items and no longer am able to locate the excludes options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Excludes
2. To the best of my knowledge, this option was never in the settings.